# The letter i looks like l in search

Tags: bug, design, search

When searching for keywords, I noticed that the lowercase letter "i" is missing the space between the line and the dot.  This makes is look like the letter "l".  This is on Firefox 27.0.1 on Windows 7, though I have not checked other browsers.

[image: i or l]

Comment: Looks the same in IE9. Link to search results: http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=looks+like

Comment: Reproduced on Firefox 27 and Opera 12.16 on Kubuntu Linux; no-repro on Chromium 32. Firefox dev tools say the font used is Open Sans Bold (woff), remotely loaded from cdn.sstatic.net.  It also seems to happen only at that specific size; zooming in or out fixes it.

Comment: Also reproduced on Chrome 33 and Firefox 27 on Windows 7.